# How to deploy React/Flask with websockets?

Tags: reactjs, flask, websocket, deployment, flask-socketio

i have a Chatting project that consists of React/Flask(Python) and I do websockets to communicate between them, how can i deploy both parts and do connect them together ?

I'm trying to deploy both of them on vercel but i figure out that vercel is not suitable for deploying backend servers on them so what should i d o ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

1st of all, you should decide, do you need it as free hosting or it is needed for your app.

But as I take it, you might need free service
So, for free service, I would suggest railway.io and fly.io
if you still want to explore more options, you can read this blog
https://dev.to/vuelancer/free-deployment-providers-bk0